# Sending email using php to multiple users with different email bodies

Tags: php, email

I've created this form to send  emails in php to all the email addresses that are saved in a database in the table named login.So I create a Send email button for each address I want to send an email.I want to send different emails to multiple users instead of sending the same email as below with the same body"hello you ve been selected".Is this possible in php?Thanks!

```html
<html >
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
   



    if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
       print("Could not connect");


 
 $query="SELECT * FROM `login`";
 if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
} else 

 while($query_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $firstname=$query_row['firstname'];
$email=$query_row['email'];
$id=$query_row['id'];
echo $firstname;
echo "<input type='submit' name='mail' value='Send email' >"; echo "<br />";
if(isset($_POST['mail'])) {
 $to='$email';
    $body='Hello!You have been selected!';
    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
      echo "mail sent to..";}
      else echo'errorr sending the email';
}
 }

  
    

    mysql_close($database);
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. Certainly something like what you show is possible, but what is your question? There is no "right" or "wrong" way to do this. That totally depends on the _why_ and _what for_ you want to do this.

Comment: Ok I edited my question.How cam I let the user to write the body of the email and not take it by default like the emil above where the body is:"Hello!You have been selected!'

Comment: I wantt o send differen emails to multiple users

Comment: Well, you have to offer some way to define the actual body. How do you want to do that? Answer that and you know how to send the messages afterwards.

Comment: I want to take the body from a form

Comment: You would have to code the body of the email somewhere, for example, you  can set variables for different users.

Comment: Then how do you want to send diffetent bodies, if one can specify only one body in a form?

Comment: What if I create the body inside this form :<form name="body"></form> and this var $_POST['body'] to put in the body of the email?